# Firebase Android Data Download Spikes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Recently I made an update to my Android app project, and as a result my downloaded data the coming two days has skyrocketed to 5 times as much data downloaded and I'm fearing it will be even higher. This is a big problem because I'm on the Blaze plan (Pay as you go). (Realtime Database)

Now I'm wondering what can cause this, I have not added alot of new singleValueEventListeners, but I have added a few completion listeners:

```
mRootRef.child("node").setValue(<value>) { error, _ ->

                       error?.let {
                            //stuff
                        } ?: kotlin.run {
                            //stuff
                        }
                    }
```

Now I'm curious if this could lead to increased volume of data downloaded if the "value" is a rather big chunk of data. In my head setValue won't affect downloaded data as you're not downloading anything (?).

The only other thing I could think of the cause for this spike is that I have started using the new firebase function to request device token:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()
            .instanceId.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                return@OnCompleteListener
            }

            task.result?.token?.let {
                myDeviceToken = it
            }
        })
```

I doubt this would be the cause but does anyone know how that works?
Would be great to be able to monitor what call/what activity that started download so much data but Firebase is kinda cryptic here. Any knowledge regarding this would be very appreciated!

Comment: There's really nothing we can do to diagnose the issue, since we can't see all the code and data, or understand how your users are using your app with that data.  What you should be doing instead is using the database profiler to get information about what's actually happening. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile

Comment: I'm with Doug here: there's not enough information for us to help you troubleshoot. In fact, none of the code you shared *reads* from the Realtime Database, so it can't be contributing to increased downloads in any way. If you keep having problems even after using the tools Doug pointed out, see if you can repro the issue in isolation following the steps in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am with @FrankvanPuffelen and Doug - there's just not enough information in the question to even guess at what the issue is. However, investigating this `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnCompleteListener` may lead to something as it appears to have been added to the main firebase node which means it would be receiving a lot of events.

Comment: @Jay If that means I'm adding something to the root ref then yeah you are right, I have an extreme amount of nodes.
Anyway, I have removed the use of both of these examples and so far today it seems like the data usage is going back to normal, although I'm still not sure why.

Comment: If that observer is on the root ref, every write to the database get's pumped back through that observer in an event - so if you write to 100 nodes, every write will trigger an event and the written data will be passed back to that observer - that adds up quickly.